# 'MyUserAdmin.fieldsets[3][1]['fields']' refers to field 'l' that is missing from the form

Tags: python, django

I have some problem with django 1.5
the backtrace is
`'MyUserAdmin.fieldsets[3][1]['fields']' refers to field 'l' that is missing from the form.`

### the code is

```
fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields':('name', 'password')}),
        ('User info', {'fields':('email',)}),
        ('Permissions',{'fields':('is_admin',)}),
        ('Important dates',{'fields':('last_login,')}),
        )
```

---

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    name = models.CharField("姓名", max_length=20, unique=True, db_index=True)
    consumption= models.DecimalField("菜品总消费", max_digits=5, decimal_places=0)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75)
    times = models.DecimalField("消费次数", max_digits=4, decimal_places=0)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'name'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', ]
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.nam
```

I can't fix it,an I don't understand the "field 'l' " means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's truly your fieldset declaration, the problem is a typo - you have the comma inside your quote marks for `last_login`.  It's iterating over the string `last_login,` as if it were a tuple of fields names.